# How to get Zone with new DateTime API in Java 8

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

With new API I can have a local date and time:

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of(9,0,0);
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.JUNE, 3);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(localDate, localTime);
System.out.println("LocalDateTime:" + localDateTime);
```

Also I can use ZoneId if I need to convert time to particular time zone:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.of("GMT"));
System.out.println("ZonedDateTime: " + zonedDateTime);

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime2 = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
System.out.println("ZonedDateTime London: " + zonedDateTime2);
```

I can get a current time by:

```
Instant currentTime = Instant.now();
```

**My question.** Is it possible to get **ZoneId and digit definition** (like +04:00) of the current time that is used on client's machine with this new API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.
[Here is documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).

Comment: Great. Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you please provide how to get a digital definition (like +04:00) of the ZoneId for full answer.

Comment: In this case use `ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(Instant.now());`
But you should know that this offset is dependent of current time (daylight time and so on)

Answer (score 0):

To get difference in seconds or hours between GMT and current time zone I can use:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeCurrent = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.now(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeGMT = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.now(), ZoneId.of("GMT"));
Duration timeZoneDifferenceDuration = Duration.between(zonedDateTimeCurrent, zonedDateTimeGMT);

System.out.println("TimeZoneDifference in seconds: " + timeZoneDifferenceDuration.getSeconds());

Double hours = (double)timeZoneDifferenceDuration.getSeconds()/(60*60);
System.out.println("TimeZoneDifference in hours: " + hours);//3.0 //4.5 //-5.0
```

However Alexanders's way seems more elegant:

> ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(Instant.now());

```
System.out.println("Offset: " + ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(Instant.now()));//+03:00
```